# setting table_cache in line with opened_tables

Tags: linux, mysql

My MySQL server is VERY busy. It has 750k opened tables. I have been reading that I should increase table_cache in line with opened_tables but I have no idea how I am meant to scale it? If I set table_cache to 750k what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you run a lot of queries that generates many temporary tables. From the comments in the doc page on [table cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-cache.html), it appears temporary tables increment the counter by 2 for each one. I don't think scaling the table_cache variable is the issue.

If you're explicitly creating temporary tables, not much that can be done except adjust your code.

Here's some more good information on temporary tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: I don't create any temporary tables myself as in create table blah. What do you mean?

Comment: I recommend reading the second link on how mysql uses temporary tables.